# Simple Trigger Beginner Prevent from delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to write my first trigger. I have table of elements. I have few records inside of it. Few records have checkbox on 1 and few on 0.

I am trying to make trigger that will prevent from delete records that have checkbox on 1 (`elm_intcolumn1`).

Trigger is working but i can't delete records with checkbox 0. Trigger is blocking all records on my elements.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[test]
    ON [dbo].[elements]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN elm_intcolumn1 = 1
            THEN 0
        WHEN elm_intcolumn1 = 0
            THEN 1
    END
    FROM elements
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('błąd', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN;
    END
END
```

Comment: Triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per *row*. If someone writes a `DELETE` that deletes (at least) one row where `elm_intcolumn1` is 1, and (at least) one row where it is 0, what do you want to happen then?

Answer (score 1):

Check about virtual tables `DELETED` and `INSERTED` -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[elements] (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    elm_intcolumn1 BIT
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.[elements] (elm_intcolumn1)
VALUES (0), (1)
GO

ALTER TRIGGER dbo.test
    ON dbo.[elements]
    AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM DELETED
        WHERE elm_intcolumn1 = 1
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('revert', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.[elements]

DELETE dbo.[elements]
WHERE id = 2
```

When delete second record:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 39
revert
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Comment: But when i delete record that have checkbox 0 he is not deleting from elements. I want only to prevent from deleting elements that have checkbox 1 .

Comment: Thank you Very much now it is working and it is little more clear for me how works triggers :)

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating your solution.

First of all - you don't need to check table on which trigger was created, instead check special table named `deleted` available in the context of `instead of delete` trigger. This table contains exactly the records you're trying to delete.

Second - your check should be simply "is there records having "elm_intcolumn1 = 1" in deleted table". If yes - then throw exception, if no such a records - then delete from the table all the records from `deleted`. Your table should has some primary key in this case (I'm assuming is it named `ID` in the sample below).

So literally it is something like:

```
if exists(select * from deleted where elm_intcolumn1 = 1)
begin
    RAISERROR ('błąd', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN;
end
else
begin
    delete from elements where ID in (select ID from deleted)
end
```

Notice you have to explicitly delete records from your table in this trigger since it is `instead of delete`, not `after delete`.

Alternatively you can change trigger type to `after delete` so explicit deletion in `else` condition branch will not be needed.